# Gradle command for deleting .gradle directory

Tags: gradle

Gradle build tool uses `.gradle` directory to hold intermediate data.

`gradle clean` command doesn't remove this directory.

Is it possible to remove everything from build with Gradle command? Like Makefile `distclean` target...

I can run `rm -r .gradle` or `hg purge --all` or `git clean` but I like pure Gradle solution.

Comment: If you're using the gradle wrapper, I don't think you want that deleted anyway

Comment: Gradle keep incremental build information in that directory. It will be counter productive to delete the directory. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: I need a command to revert source tree into original clean state. Seems that Gradle doesn't supports that and as I wrote I can do that via `git`/`hg` in any case.

Comment: Create a .gitignore file in your project directory and add .gradle to the .gitignore so that git wont consider that directory for version control.